# Can the process of adiabatic quantum optimization be simply a reverse of spontaneous synchronization?

Tags: adiabatic-model

I assume we can model a complex potential by many harmonic oscillators with many different couplings and with added to their potentials different constants so that the system has many local minima and they are not equidistant. In that way we receive a rugged energy landcsape.
A spontaneous synchronization would result in reduction of this energy landscape to a single well/harmonic oscillator potential. So starting in an unkown ground state of the initial complex potential we would finish the evolution in a known ground state of the harmonic oscillator.
If my resoning is correct this process would be quite similar (or even equivalent) to the reverse process of quantum adiabatic optimization, however, I'm not fully sure if my latter assumptions are fully correct.